# A way to create a time delay without the use of time.sleep() in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm fairly new to coding in general. This is for an assignment and I'm only allowed to use os and datetime module so yeah. Just wanna replicate the effect of this: (But without the use of time.sleep())

```
import time
def _loader(s):
    while s > 0:
        time.sleep(0.33)
        print(" . ", end="")
        s = s - 1
    time.sleep(0.33)
    print("\n")
```

I've tried this but it just produces an error when i try to subtract the two

```
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime
def _loader(s):
    while s > 0:
        t1 = timedelta(datetime.now())
        t2 = timedelta(seconds=0.33)
        while 1 == 1:
            t1temp = timedelta(datetime.now())
            if t1temp - t1 < t2:
                continue
            else:
                break
        print(" . ", end="")
        s = s - 1
```

Comment: What's the error? With traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is in the use of datetime.now()
Try it in this way:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime
def _loader(s):
    while s > 0:
        t1 = datetime.now()
        t2 = timedelta(seconds=0.33)
        while 1 == 1:
            t1temp = datetime.now()
            if t1temp - t1 < t2:
                continue
            else:
                break
        print(" . ", end="")
        s = s - 1
```